# Postgres update with replace

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-9.4

I am doing  select which is:

```
SELECT replace(field_1, E'<div class="ad-content"><div class="ad-title">publicidade</div><div id=\'div-gpt-ad-1426519214388-1\'> <script type=\'text/javascript\'>googletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.display(\'div-gpt-ad-1426519214388-1\');});</script> </div></div>', '') FROM test
```

An that returns what I want, but when I try to update doing the same thing, It doesn't work as expected:

```
UPDATE test SET field_1 = replace(field_1, E'<div class="ad-content"><div class="ad-title">publicidade</div><div id=\'div-gpt-ad-1426519214388-1\'> <script type=\'text/javascript\'>googletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.display(\'div-gpt-ad-1426519214388-1\');});</script> </div></div>', '')
```

It doesn't update the column without the

```
<div class="ad-content"><div class="ad-title">publicidade</div><div id=\'div-gpt-ad-1426519214388-1\'> <script type=\'text/javascript\'>googletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.display(\'div-gpt-ad-1426519214388-1\');});</script> </div></div>
```

Comment: It does update them, it just updates them to the same value they already had.  Why did you think it would do something different?  Why do you think it should do something different?  Why do you think it did do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `SELECT` works as expected, so should your `UPDATE`. More: it should update *all* columns, which is most probably not what you want.

```
UPDATE test
SET    field_1 = replace(field_1, $$<div class="ad-content"><div class="ad-title">publicidade</div><div id='div-gpt-ad-1426519214388-1'> <script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1426519214388-1');});</script> </div></div>$$, '')
WHERE  field_1              LIKE $$%<div class="ad-content"><div class="ad-title">publicidade</div><div id='div-gpt-ad-1426519214388-1'> <script type='text/javascript'>googletag.cmd.push(function(){googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1426519214388-1');});</script> </div></div>%$$
```

I added a `WHERE` clause to avoid expensive and pointless empty updates.

Related:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)
- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Comment: Tnx for `WHERE` clause trick, I was getting to severe performance issues whole day until I found this trick